# whar will be the value of TH1 to access the HC-05 bluetooth module using AT89S52 microcontroller using baud rate 38400

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, uart

To access bluetooth module in AT command mode required baud rate 38400.so what will be the value of TH1 .crystal value 11.0592 mhz.

Answer (score 0):

For Serial Communication between HC-05 with any controller is 38400 by default.
To set baudrate of AT89S52 Timer 2 is used as it is explained in its datasheet

See page 14 and 15 of Datasheet

http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1919.pdf